# Loading Angular with jQuery causes a failure to invoke script onload callback

Tags: jquery, angularjs, onload

I'd like to dynamically load a JavaScript library, say for example D3.js, with an Angular service something like this one:

```
function factoryD3Loading ($q, $document, $rootScope, $window) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    var script = $document[0].createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = 'async';
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js';
    script.onload = function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            d.resolve($window.d3);
        });
    };
    $document.find('body').append(script);
    return d.promise;
}
```

It works great *unless* I load Angular with jQuery instead of letting it use its built-in jqLite by default. From what I can tell, the `onload` callback is simply never invoked when Angular is using jQuery. It's definitely invoked when Angular is just using jqLite.

Here's a [non-working fiddle using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/3d5s5u4d/), and here's a [working fiddle without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/3d5s5u4d/1/). Note that these are identical except for whether jQuery is loaded.

So, a two-part question:

1. **Why does usage of jQuery cause this difference in behavior?**
2. **How can this with-jQuery behavior be corrected or worked around?**

As for why, my guess is that jqLite is somehow configured with the digest cycle in a way that Angular doesn't (or can't?) configure for jQuery. If that guess is accurate, this behavior seems inconsistent and strange to the point of being a bug (in Angular, that is).

As for how, I think (but haven't yet tested) that I can load jQuery after Angular and do some ugly unwrap/rewrap to "convert" jqLite objects to have jQuery's full API when I need it. I'd prefer a cleaner approach, if one exists.

Comment: consider using require.js or common.js etc. (see http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/ for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug in Angular... It's happening because jQuery.append handles script elements in a special way, basically loading any `src` URL on a script element separately through jQuery Ajax. `load` is then fired on `window`, not on the script element. jqLite.append does not emulate this aspect of jQuery.append.

The solution is to append using the DOM instead of angular.element:

```
function factoryD3Loading ($q, $document, $rootScope, $window) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    var script = $document[0].createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = 'async';
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js';
    script.onload = function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            d.resolve($window.d3);
        });
    };
    $document[0].body.appendChild(script); // DOM, not angular.element
    return d.promise;
}
```

With this change, behavior is consistent between jqLite-Angular and jQuery-Angular.